# How to change currency symbol OR add own currency

Tags: magento2, currency

Is there a way to add an own currency? Like "Points".

I tried to write a plugin to intercept after `\Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency::getCurrencySymbol` but it seems, that this method is not used to format price for frontend.

My Plugin looks like

class PluginAfter
{

```
/**
 * @param string $interceptedInput
 * @param string $interceptedOutput
 *
 * @return string 'Points'
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function afterGetCurrencySymbol($interceptedInput, $interceptedOutput)
{
    die('getCurrencySymbol'); // not triggered

    return __('Points');
}
```

So i tried to intercept `\Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency::getCurrency`
but there is no option to set new currencysymbol

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed changing the currency symbol via **event/observer** according to `magento/module-currency-symbol` and `magento/module-currency-symbol/Observer/CurrencyDisplayOptions.php`

Comment: can u post your code asap?

Comment: asap? rly? let me look for it

Comment: what happened ? u lost it?

Comment: @KevinKrieger, pls update the code

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing out the file,

I can add that is no need to implement an observer for that.

You can add a `customsymbol` node in your own module in `config.xml`:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <currency>
            <options>
                <customsymbol>a:1:{s:3:"RON";s:3:"Lei";}</customsymbol>
            </options>
        </currency>

        <!-- ... -->

    </default>

    <!-- ... -->

</config>
```

Where RON is my currency code ( similar to USD for american dollar ), and Lei is my new currency symbol I want to use.

Notice that the accepted value is only a serialized array with currency code as key and custom currency symbol as value.

Thanks!

Comment: i did this and nothing changed .... should i see the new symbol in Currency setup section of admin?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the solution Kevin Krieger posted. So create/edit `config.xml` file in any module and instead of a serialized array add a JSON array.

Using a serialized array caused an exception in my case (Unable to unserialize array - while it was acutally a valid string), but using JSON worked for me.

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <currency>
            <options>
                <customsymbol>{"RSD":"rsd"}</customsymbol>
            </options>
        </currency>
    </default>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You guys can use this extension.

https://marketplace.magento.com/extrembler-overridecurrencysymbol.html

It works as per store views.

Thanks